# QUERY DATABASE: How can I get multiple data from 2 tables with an id that does not exist in a table

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, database

Hello i've got the following two tables:

TABLE: computers
| id       | pc     | user_id |
|:---|:---- -|:----|
| 1   | M-1   | 25  |
| 2   | P-1   | 15  |
| 3   | C-2   | 36  |
| 4   | A-5   | 0   |
| 5   | G-3   | 0   |

TABLE: users
| id       | name     | users_id |
|:---|:-------|:----|
| 1   | John   | 25  |
| 2   | Mark   | 15  |
| 3   | Tom   | 36  |

I would like get this result
| id(computers)     | name_computer     | name_user |
|:---|:-----|:--------|
| 1   | M-1   | John  |
| 2   | P-1   | Mark  |
| 3   | C-2   | Tom  |
| 4   | A-5   | (0 or empty)   |
| 5   | G-3   | (0 or empty)   |

But when i try to get that i get this result

| id(computers)     | name_pc     | user_id |
|:---|:------|:------|
| 1   | M-1   | John  |
| 2   | P-1   | Mark  |
| 3   | C-2   | Tom  |
| 4   | A-5   | John   |
| 4   | A-5   | Mark   |
| 4   | A-5   | Tom   |
| 5   | G-3   | John   |
| 5   | G-3   | Mark   |
| 5   | G-3   | Tom   |

I get computer id 4 and 5 with all posible usernames.

In this case user_id '0' dont exist but i wish the result of the value = (0 or empty)

Its possible get result i would like? Thanks
In fact, i want get id of computer, name of computer and name of user but if id 0 dont exist i dont know what i do

Comment: Please include the code that generates your result.

Comment: Cerdito, please try to format your tables properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a `left join`:

```
select c.*, u.name
from computers c left join
     users u
     on c.user_id = u.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a [Left join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table 2
ON table1.pk = table2.fk
```

All rows on the left side should be displayed, and the data on the right should correspond to the data on the left. If there is no corresponding data on the right, it will just display asa null

Comment: Thanks you! Works!